# She must be sick again / she must have been sick again

Tags: exam-questions

> She is absent, she **must be/ must have been** sick again.

What is the difference in the meaning of the two sentences and which one is correct to use here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***She must be sick*** is in the present tense. The sentence is saying that it is likely that the person is sick right now.

***She must have been sick*** is expressing past probability. The sentence is saying that the person was probably sick in the past. You can read more about it here:

http://speakspeak.com/resources/english-grammar-rules/modal-verbs/past-probability-must-have-cant-have-couldnt-have

To clarify: the 2nd option doesn't really make sense in your situation, so I recommend choosing the first option.

Comment: This is not quite accurate for the question as written.  If she is absent *now*, why is it relevant to guess she had been sick in the past?  The first is fine, but in the second the grammar doesn't make sense.

Comment: Are you saying I should pick one of the two possibilities as the correct one? Not really sure what you're saying

Comment: I would edit the answer to point out the inconsistency, so the learner doesn't  think it's ok.  Assuming you agree with me, that is.  I could be wrong.

Comment: I assume OP would glean that the second doesn't make sense, but will attempt to clarify

Answer (score 0):

The sentence itself is a case of [comma splicing](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/engagement/2/1/34/) where two independent clauses are combined using a comma.
The first independent clause "She is absent" is in the present tense.

For both of the options you have presented, the "must" implies [speculation](http://www.headsupenglish.com/index.php/upper-intermediate-students/upper-intermediate-skill-builders/upper-intermediate-grammar/341-modals-of-speculation). "Be" is the infinitive while the compound "have been" is the past participle.

Because we are speculating on the reason why the subject is presently absent, we must be remarking upon the current state of her health. So in the context of this sentence the tense of "to be" should be present. Making the correct form of **this sentence**:

**"She is absent. She must be sick again."**

However, the desired tense may change depending on the speculated *cause* of her absence. If, for example, the subject were late for the bus, the desired tense would be the past participle. This is because it was something in the past which caused her to presently be absent in contrast to your example where it is something true presently that is causing her to presently be absent.

**"She is absent. She must have been late for the bus again."**

Answer (score 0):

> She must be sick again.

The speaker states that she was sick in the past and that the speaker has reason to believe she is sick again now.

> She must have been sick again.

The speaker states that she was sick in the past and that the speaker has reason to believe she was sick again recently.